# Set format for all cells in Excel without selections, using C# and VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, format, vsto, cell

Let's assume that I want to set the format ("Text", "Number", "Percent", "Date", and so on) **for all cells** in the Excel worksheet.

I now how to set the format for a single row or a single column. For example, the code setting the "Percent" format for all cells of the 3rd row looks as follows (the decimal delimiter depends on your Windows localization):

```
this.worksheet.Rows[3].NumberFormat = "%0,00";
```

However, when I'm trying to do the same for all cells of the worksheet with the following code:

```
this.worksheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "%0,00";
```

, I get a problem - in fact, the format of the cells **will be changed** but to a some wrong format (in the present case, the real set format will be "#000%", which is recognized by Excel as a "Custom Format").

I know how to solve this problem using selections. So, the following code performs the mentioned task perfectly:

```
this.worksheet.Cells.Select();
this.worksheet.Application.Selection.NumberFormat = "%0,00";
```

, however, I really want to solve this problem without selections. **How can I do it?**

Comment: one thought is not actually format *the entire set of cells* in a worksheet as this could lead to problems down the road if you have formats in **every** cell, even though a lot of cells do not have data. The alternative would be to define the range of cells that will (or may) have data and only format those.

Comment: No, exactly entire set of cells is needed to be formatted, independently of whether a cell is empty or contains a value.

Comment: but for the **entire worksheet** or just the range of cells that (may or may not) contain data?

Comment: Excel simply doesn't keep record of unused cells for efficiency reasons. You virtually see a worksheet full of cells in the UI but they -are not there- in the file. To show you proof of this, save an empty Excel Workbook to disk, rename it to .zip and look at the internals. Your proposal, similar to the Select method, is not recommended as this will bloat your file significantly and performance will drop. I also don't think your comment "Please, read ... about nothing" is helpful and even offending to the community members like @ScottHoltzman spending their time to help you solve your problem.

Comment: "... will bloat your file significantly". Did you try to do it before writing your comment? I have just created two .xlsx-files: one with **all** cells of the General type (that is default), another - with **all** cells of the Date type. All cells in both files are empty. The result size of both files is nearly the same and not big: about 7-8 **Kilo**Bytes. Something works differently than you thought, do you agree? On this, let me finish to spend my time to explain you my question and how Excel works .

Comment: I was talking about the concept in general, how Excel is designed. In your case it is 'just' a NumberFormat, but it will for instance immediately show if you do the same thing adding the same Formula to ALL cells. Excel will even warn you that you might run out of memory. I edited my answer one more time to give it a last try, hopefully you can respond somewhat less negative to your helping hands and focus on how to get things solved.

Comment: Let's stop it! I have already told you that your imagination about how Excel works "in general" is not applicable for this concrete case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question.

If shortly, instead of the code

```
this.worksheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "%0,00";
```

, one should use the following one:

```
((dynamic)this.worksheet.Cells).NumberFormat = "%0,00";
```

Then, the result format will be correct!

Now, my explanation of this: The `NumberFormat` property looks to be **correctly** applicable only for the `dynamic` type, but not for the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range` type. When one writes something like `this.worksheet.Cells` or `this.worksheet.Range["A1", "C3"]`, he/she gets the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range` type; when one writes something like `this.worksheet.Rows[3]`, he/she gets the `dynamic` type. Therefore, in order to use the `NumberFormat` property, just cast your `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range` object to the `dynamic` one!

Answer (score 1):

Although I find your responses to people trying to help you very offensive I tried to ignore that a bit to keep in mind that we try to help each other here and focus on finding a solution for the scenario.

So here is my final attempt to please you ...

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestExcelNumberFormatOnWholeSheet()
{
    Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
    excel.Visible = true;

    Excel.Workbook workbook1 = excel.Workbooks.Add();
    Excel.Worksheet sheet = workbook1.Sheets.Add();

    var lastCol = sheet.Range["a1"].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlToRight].Column;
    var lastRow = sheet.Cells[65536, lastCol].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlDown].Row;

    sheet.Range["a1", sheet.Cells[lastRow, lastCol]].NumberFormat = "%0,00";
}
```

I've tested it here and seems to work (keep in mind that as you already mentioned you may need to switch the decimal character depending on your localization).

Comment: Added to that, the 'custom' format you see in the cells is where the content of the cells are not matching with the NumberFormat provided. You therefor may ask yourself if it is useful to set all cells to a specific NumberFormat if you know not all cells will match the pattern.

Comment: Just concerning your code: the "used range" is not interesting to me! And the different worksheets in the same workbook are also not interesting to me! I am interested only in **one single worksheet** but in **all cells in this worksheet** (all cells but not only the cells from the "used range").

Comment: This is just the way Excel works @Jordan . This is done for efficiency reasons, if Excel would create instances for each cell that has not been used the file would become a lot bigger, performance would go down etc. That also explains why there is no option to set the NumberFormat on all, even unused, cells to address in one call. And as you indicate you only want one single worksheet, just remove the foreach loop ...

Comment: Excel does not create instances **of cells** when the type **of the worksheet** is changed. Does not create, Karl !!! And, please, do not explain me how the `foreach` works!

Comment: Okay, you have corrected your answer and your code. Have you really tried to perform this code before posting it? In my case, the code like `this.worksheet.Range["A1", "C3"].NumberFormat = "%0,00";` sets in fact a wrong format, namely "#000%". Exactly the same problem as described in my initial post.

Comment: Actually I did, and found the same thing unless you change the decimal character. But I'm done here ...